# Exercises and diets to reduce waist & chest size

Tags: exercise, diet, bellyfat, ketogenic-diet, paleo-diet

I have bigger tummy and male boobs.

[image]

[image]

I'm ready to follow some serious diet and I can spend 2 hours for gym exercise.

When I was searching for diets.

I feel Keto or Paleo diet can help me I guess. But I would like to hear some suggestions from you people.

[image]

As far as exercise is concerned , I'm doing complete cardio burning 250 calorie at-least.

[image]

Please suggest me some good exercises as well.

FYI:

- I have some 6 fat balls in my hand and leg.
- My family has some
  history of Diabetes.
- I don't want to lose my hair.
- In Long run I want
  to get good atheletic body ( My ass is small want to make it lil big, have to get sone good arm size and shoulder size )

[image]

Comment: There is only one way to lose weight, forget all this fancy stuff made for magazines. Eat less than you burn. Anyhow, people can suggest you exercises, but only at random. What do you like doing? Just cardio? Well, what's wrong with what you are doing currently? Also, what has losing your hair to do with anything?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Sometimes when people follow certain diet , they tend to lose hair as they are omiting some foods.

Comment: @Naveen - No one is suggesting omitting foods (yet). Simply making sure that you have good portion control, and don't over-eat is enough to cause a caloric deficit, which then leads to weight loss. Exercise is a secondary tool for weight loss.

Comment: As it stands, it looks like you're asking for a complete diet plan and exercise routine. That's not really something we do on this site, because over the Internet, it's impossible for us to get all the facts required to make these things. A doctor or a personal trainer who can see you in person is really the only way to make sure you get a program specifically for you, your goals, and your current state. Also, a good program changes along the way, so you need follow-up.